# extracting information from xml

Tags: xml, xpath

May I know how I can extract 2,34 from the following piece of html by using xpath? I am using htmlceaner to this end and I think I cannot use normalize-space() and notice that I should use the  tag value because otherwise there are lots of returned values. Also,  xyz value has many spaces around it. I have omitted the rest of the html for illustration.

`<tr><td colspan="2"> <strong>
XYZ </strong> </td><td align="right"> <strong> 2,34&nbsp; </strong> </td>`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
substring-before(/*/td[2]/strong, '&#xA0;')
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(/*/td[2]/strong, '&#xA0;')"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be made well-formed):

```
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <strong> XYZ </strong>
    </td>
    <td align="right">
        <strong> 2,34&#xA0;; </strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**The XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
 2,34
```